# Raycaster camera with a-sky intersects with cursor

Tags: aframe

I just started developing with a-frame, please excuse if the answer is obvious.
In my project I would like to get the position of a-sky where the user is looking at. Therefor I implemented a raycaster within the camera, which works fine so far.

HTML

```
<a-camera listener>
    <a-entity raycaster="far: 1000" position="0 -0.9 0" rotation="0 0 0"></a-entity>
</a-camera>

<a-sky follow-intersection
     id="sky"
     src="#skybox-image">

</a-sky>
```

TS

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("follow-intersection", {
  init: function() {
    this.el.addEventListener("raycaster-intersected", evt => {
      this.intersectingRaycaster = evt.detail.el.components.raycaster;
    });
    this.el.addEventListener("raycaster-intersected-cleared", () => {
      this.intersectingRaycaster = null;
    });
  },
  tick: function(t) {

      if (!this.intersectingRaycaster) {
        return;
      }

      const intersection = this.intersectingRaycaster.getIntersection(this.el);

      if (intersection) {
        let point = intersection.uv;
        console.log(point.x, point.y);
      }
```

So far this works fine, the problem is that after I set the cursor in the scene (which is needed for the project)

```
<a-scene
  cursor="rayOrigin: listener"
>
```

I always get the intersections with the cursor, which are not wanted.

How can I only get the intersections of the camera? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the cursor in `a-scene` is needed. You could just do:

```
<a-camera listener>
    <a-entity cursor raycaster="far: 1000" position="0 -0.9 0" rotation="0 0 0"></a-entity>
</a-camera>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunateley the cursor is needed for other interactions in the project